# box2d debug draw not working

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to use box2d's debug draw in an IOS project, using what seems like the correct code, but nothing is showing on the screen. This is the code:

```
b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
_world = new b2World(gravity);
_world->SetContinuousPhysics(true);
m_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw( PTM_RATIO );
_world->SetDebugDraw(m_debugDraw);
uint32 flags = 0;
flags += b2Draw::e_shapeBit;
flags += b2Draw::e_jointBit;
flags += b2Draw::e_centerOfMassBit;
flags += b2Draw::e_aabbBit;
flags += b2Draw::e_pairBit;
m_debugDraw->SetFlags(flags);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the **draw** method.

```
- (void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position);
    kmGLPushMatrix();
    world->DrawDebugData();
    kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin. Should I include some class so that ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position) and kmGLPushMatrix compile?

Comment: You need to include GLES-Render.h

Comment: I'm still getting 'Use of undeclared identifier kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position', and the compiler is also offering to replace kmGLPushMatrix (and the pop) with glPushMatrix (and the pop.) So only the first error is still there.

Comment: Do you have "cocos2d.h" included as well? I'm using Kobold2D and it may include some files I'm not aware of.

Comment: Yes, cocos2d.h is in there.

Comment: This works: http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/09/wrapping-box2d-debug-into-a-cocos2d-layer/  Thanks @Martin when you said that you're using Kobold2D and I saw in the linked tutorial that it's part of Kobold2D I knew it's probably going to work. So you really did help. If you want to edit the answer to reflect it I'll be happy to except it.

Comment: Well you don't have to include Kobold2D, just the debug draw layer from this tutorial. http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/09/wrapping-box2d-debug-into-a-cocos2d-layer/

Comment: You're right about that. Anyway, that's something you found yourself so you don't have to accept my answer.

Comment: I would have liked to because you did help. But anyway, at leaset I voted it up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution brought by John Wordsworth here http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/09/wrapping-box2d-debug-into-a-cocos2d-layer/ works perfectly for me.